# VBA code to superscript a number after decimal point

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

What will be the VBA code to detect a decimal point of a number in a cell and then superscript the numbers after the decimal?

For instance in the number 3.45 I wish to superscript 45 and then remove the decimal point.

I know how to change the value of cells but don't understand how to manipulate the string to include superscripts.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/5638-superscript-subscript-part-cell-using-visual-basic-applications.html#

Answer (score 1):

```
Length = Len(ActiveCell.Value)
For i = 1 To Length
    If (Mid(ActiveCell.Value, i, 1) = ".") Then
        ActiveCell.Value = "'" & Left(ActiveCell.Value, i - 1) & Right(ActiveCell.Value, Length - i)
        ActiveCell.Characters(i, Length - i).Font.Superscript = True
        ActiveCell.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

I believe that most of this is self-explanatory.

```
Left(ActiveCell.Value, i - 1) & Right(ActiveCell.Value, Length - i)
```

rebuilds the contents of the cell
with the substring to the left of the `.` (in your example, `3`)
concatenated with the substring to the right of the `.` (`45`),
leaving out the `.` itself. 
I stuck a `'` in front of it to turn it into text —
apparently you can’t format individual characters in a numeric value. 
I set the horizontal alignment to right because that’s normal for numbers,
but the cell is now text and defaults to being left-aligned.